# How can I use Speech Recognition in Django on the client side?

Tags: javascript, django

I am writing an application in Django. There should be a field to fill in, which the user should be able to fill in by voice. He should see what he dictated and, if an error occurs, be able to fix it quickly.

```
I wrote an html file with a small script in js inside. Here are its contents:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="the_button" type="button" value="Click to Speak">
    <input id="the_form" type="text" name="q" size=80 >

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var SpeechRecognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition
         || window.mozSpeechRecognition || window.msSpeechRecognition)();

        const the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
        the_button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            SpeechRecognition.start();
        })

        SpeechRecognition.onresult = function(event){
            var the_text = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            document.getElementById('the_form').value = the_text;
        };

        SpeechRecognition.onend = function(){
            SpeechRecognition.stop();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This html file works fine when I open it in the browser. But when I integrate this file into my Django project in the developer console I get an error in the line:

```
var SpeechRecognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition
   || window.mozSpeechRecognition || window.msSpeechRecognition)();
```

I installed SpeechRecognition modules in my Django project, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my problem. 
I would be grateful for any advice on how I can use SpeechRecognition on the client side

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The problem wasn't Django - it's just that not all browsers support SpeachRecognition. I opened my project in Google Chrome and everything works)..